# How can I perform the json request in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to develop a python client for `Pocket` (formerly read it later).

I am studying the OAuth process of [it](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication). And be stuck here. How can I perform this request and get the response?

```
POST /v3/oauth/request HTTP/1.1
Host: getpocket.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Accept: application/json

{"consumer_key":"1234-abcd1234abcd1234abcd1234",
"redirect_uri":"pocketapp1234:authorizationFinished"}
```

I am new to python. This is I have tried. But I can not get the response I want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2
import json

def main():
    # Whatever structure you need to send goes here:
    jdata = json.dumps({"consumer_key":"1234-abcd1234abcd1234abcd1234", "redirect_uri":"pocketapp1234:authorizationFinished"})
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://getpocket.com", jdata)
    the_page = response.read()
    print the_page

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for this sort of work. (EDITED)

```
import requests
import json


data = {"consumer_key": "..."}
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
response = requests.post("http://getpocket.com", data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
response.json
```

Comment: This line :`POST /v3/oauth/request HTTP/1.1` is not needed?

Comment: Oops, sorry, see edit above. No, it isn't -- that's part of making a POST request.